# Is there a way to manually set pm2's app version meta-data

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a simple `pm2` config containing some app's;

```
{
    name: "App1",
    script: "/home/scripts/websockets/app1-websocket.js",
    instances: 1,
    log_date_format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
    out_file : "/dev/null",
    restart_delay : 30000,
    max_restarts : 5,
    exp_backoff_restart_delay: 500,
    namespace: "APPS",
},
{
    name: "App2",
    script: "/home/scripts/websockets/app2-websocket.js",
    instances: 1,
    log_date_format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
    out_file : "/dev/null",
    restart_delay : 30000,
    max_restarts : 5,
    exp_backoff_restart_delay: 500,
    namespace: "APPS",
}
```

This is all local files and I'm not looking to bundle them into git or similar for such a small project. I'd like to know if there is a way to manually set the `version` meta-data field shown in `pm2 ls` as that way we can still set & track what's running.

Current:

```
│ 0   │ App1    │ APPS       │ N/A     │ fork    │ 1234    │ 7m     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 33.2mb   │ lusr     │ disabled │
│ 1   │ App2    │ APPS       │ N/A     │ fork    │ 1235    │ 14h    │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 9.4mb    │ lusr     │ disabled │
```

Desired:

```
│ 0   │ App1    │ APPS       │ 3.1.2     │ fork    │ 1234    │ 7m     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 33.2mb   │ lusr     │ disabled │
│ 1   │ App2    │ APPS       │ 2.1.0     │ fork    │ 1235    │ 14h    │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 9.4mb    │ lusr     │ disabled │
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much being distracted with packaging app's and all that other stuff it's not actually needed for most basic setup and I wish the doc's where more clear.

All you need to do is put the script or app you are executing into it's own directory along with a file called `package.json` and update the config with the new path. It doesn't matter what the thing is your running from `pm2` long as it's in it's own folder;

```
{
    name: "App1",
    script: "/home/scripts/websockets/app1/app1-websocket.js",
    instances: 1,
    log_date_format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
    out_file : "/dev/null",
    restart_delay : 30000,
    max_restarts : 5,
    exp_backoff_restart_delay: 500,
    namespace: "APPS",
},
```

Then in `/home/scripts/websockets/app1/` we have the `app1.js` & `package.json` files.

Inside the `package.json` all you need to specify is;

```
{
    "name" : "App1",
    "version" : "1.1.0",
    "description": "App Scripts"
}
```

Then delete and reload the process with `pm2 delete 0` `pm2 start config.js --only app1`

```
pm2 info App1

version │ 1.1.0
```

Now it shows my desired version number... BUT REMEMBER... As this is linked to a static file you will need to manually update the `package.json` file with any changes to the version number.